# mvvmcross ios lock portrait orientation for specific MvxViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have solution in Xamarin mvvmcross which support for IOS portrait and landscape screen orientations. IOS 8.0
I would like to add new MvxViewController but lock it only on Portrait mode.
I searched in Internet examples for ios swift, xamarin forms but all of this are not applied for mvvmcross solution
Is there way how I can lock Portrait mode only for one screen with Xamarin mvvmcroos?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no different from a normal ViewController.

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate() => false;
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations() => 
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I added code to my Controller but ShouldAutorotate still isn't called .        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            var presenter = new MvxIosViewPresenter(this, window);

            var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
            setup.Initialize();

            var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
            startup.Start();
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            return true;
        }

Comment: Maybe I need to change something in my mvvmcross AppDelegate file? Thank you

Comment: I think apple have changed the way that rotations work in iOS 8 onwards. I know it's definitely different in iOS 10.

Comment: I you want to restrict orientation to several variants, for example UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape (it includes both landscape sides), you should set ShouldAutorotate to true.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for me is working this method : 
in App AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate class i created

```
public bool RestrictRotation = true;
```

and added method :

```
[Export("application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:")]
public UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, IntPtr forWindow)
{
    if (this.RestrictRotation)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}
```

then for view where I want only Portrait mode, I use

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    AppDelegate app = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    app.RestrictRotation = false;
}
```

and for support all screen rotations I am setting :

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    AppDelegate app = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    app.RestrictRotation = true;
}
```

Hope it will help!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was needing an app that is all portrait except certain modal views are landscape, so I did it like this for iOS 10 on MvvmCross 5.0:

Firstly set the orientations your app will need in the Info.plist.

Then you will need to find your `[MvxRootPresentation]`, aka your root view.

The root view is the one that will receive the calls from `ShouldAutorotate` & `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` I then pass these down to the visible controllers if they implement the methods both these methods are virtual so if not implemented the default is ShouldRotate = false GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations = AllButUpsideDown

Add `ShouldAutorotate` & `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` methods in the root view like this:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
{
    return true; // Allows all view to auto rotate if they are wrong orientation
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
{
    var orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;

    if (VisibleUIViewController != null)
    {
        var VisibleMvxViewController = VisibleUIViewController as MvxViewController;
        if (VisibleMvxViewController != null)
        {
            // Check if the view is a Modal View by checking for the MvxModalPresentationAttribute
            var attribute = VisibleMvxViewController.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MvxModalPresentationAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as MvxModalPresentationAttribute;
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                // Visible view is a modal
                if (!VisibleUIViewController.IsBeingDismissed)
                {
                    // view is not being dismissed so use the orientation of the modal
                    orientation = VisibleUIViewController.GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

Then on modal views (that have the MvxModalPresentation attribute in my case) you want to change the orientation override this method:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
}
```

This solution means you don't need to add any thing to the AppDelegate